# Rake Migration: How to enter an auth_token into a migration for all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I recently added a new column called `auth_token` to my users which is suppose to be generated when the new user is created.

How do I add an `auth_token` to my existing users via migrations?
Source: http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

ps. I cannot find this in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html so please don't send me there.

Comment: Are you trying to add `auth_token` to existing users?

Comment: I think you should use `db/seeds.rb` instead of adding a new migration class. You want to use migration when you need to alter the database structure not its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DoThisThing < ActiveRecord:: Migration
   def self.up
      @users = Users.all
      @users.each do |user|
         user.auth_token = generate_token
         user.save
      end
   end
   def self.down
      puts "non recoverable migration"
   end
   def generate_token
      123456789
   end
end
```

You can put any standard Ruby/Rails code you like into a migration. Just be mindful of stdin/out and whether or not any particular libs you'd need are loaded into the memory space of the migration.

Comment: You could SHA the login name and created at to get something unique for every user, but something like this would work.

Comment: Could you explain your method as well wesgarrison? It's always good to know various methods of doing something.

Comment: The migration you've mentioned above is not working. I'm getting errors in the "up" part :(

Comment: Can you post the error? I use code like this in my migrations pretty frequently. What happens if you do a rake db:migrate --trace

Comment: Can't :/ I already reset my database to enter the users all over again >.>